# Maximum speed based on atmospheric altitude given maximum temp?

Tags: failure, atmospheric-drag, thermal, heat-shield, heat

I saw the question [Could escape velocity be achieved in the atmosphere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35172/12102) and thought it probably could've been asked better.

I'm sure there's an equation to calculate the average heat generated by an object traveling in the atmosphere. More specifically, I am asking for an equation simplified based on the following variables:

- Speed of Object
- Height of Atmosphere (or density of atmosphere)

Which results in:

- Heat/Energy Applied to Object

Taking this even further I would like my rocket to be made out of something which has a melting point of 1,650 °C (3,000 °F) (atmospheric re-entry for the average space shuttle mission).

**Can anyone provide me a graph for how fast I am able to go at altitude $X$ without melting?**

You may make any assumptions you would like, I do not mind an ideal world here. I would love to see this done with equations if possible.

Comment: Slightly related [What aspects of reentry heating 'scale as the 8th power'?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24902/12102)

Comment: @uhoh is there a meta exchange post on those... LaTeX style equations? Markup wise? I wanted to use some earlier.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/284619) I just type "mathjax stackexchange" into a search engine to find it each time.

Comment: I suspect this is too broad. I'd be very surprised if there were "an equation" - shape of the object would influence the amount of heat it had to handle; materials would have impacts on what it could handle and cooling system would dictate how it would handle it.

Answer (score 4):

This is just silly enough to be fun. Here is the requested plot:

[image: Max velocity for given equilibrium temperature]

[NASA Aerothermodynamics Course Lecture Notes](https://tfaws.nasa.gov/TFAWS12/Proceedings/Aerothermodynamics%20Course.pdf) has all of the equations I used:

- Sutton-Graves Convective Heating: $$\dot{q}_{conv}=k(\frac{\rho}{R_n})^\frac{1}{2}V^3$$
  where $k=1.7415*10^{-4}$ for Earth.
- Martin Radiative Heating: $$\dot{q}_{rad}=\rho^{1.6}R_n^{1.0}V^{8.5}$$
- Total heating rate is the sum of convective and radiative. With radiative equilibrium assumed: $$\dot{q}_{rerad}=\dot{q}_{conv}+\dot{q}_{rad}=\epsilon\sigma T^4, \sigma=5.67*10^{-8}$$
- I assumed a blackbody radiator ($\epsilon=1$) and a nose radius of 1 meter ($1650 °C=1923 K$).
- Solve for velocity V.

I used [Wikipedia's International Standard Atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Atmosphere) and the mean solar activity model for extended altitudes from [Braeunig Rocket & Space Technology](http://www.braeunig.us/space/atmos.htm) to find the density ($\rho$) at various altitudes.

**Important:** these are just engineering models, not proper "physics-like" equations, they are moderately accurate when used properly and *highly* inaccurate when used like this, but hey, we're having some fun here :). I've noted the approximate region of validity for these models in the image below.

It is also important to consider that this is all steady-state modeling. It would take some time to reach the max temperature from ambient temperature and there's not much time be had at some of these speeds!

I made an excel file that will take your inputs of nose radius and temperature limits to automatically calculate the max velocity for this steady-state  temperature and configuration. It is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/BrendanLuke15/SX_SE_Repo/tree/main/35223):
[image: excel file usage]